# apache flink to process only x% of events in a tumbling windows

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

I have an AWS kinesis data stream continuously receiving events and these events are sent to kinesis data analytics to get metrics over a tumbling window using apache flink.

is it possible to dump x% of random data in a tumbling window to s3 bucket? if yes, please share the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your tumbling window output, if it is not aggregated, I assume will be some kind of `Seq[Element]`. The simplest approach I can think of would be to sample the elements you want to store in S3 using a `flatMap` operator and connect the output to a `FileSink` writing to S3.

The code will look quite different depending on the output format. The simplest example would be:

```
val windowOutStream: Seq[Element] = ...
val sampledOutStream: Seq[String] = windowOutStream.flatMap(window => {
// iterate over all the elements in the window
// filter the ones you want to store to S3
// encode the element as a string and add the window start/end times so you can later identify to which window they belonged to
})

// writeAsText will write each element in a new line in the same file
sampledOutStream.writeAsText("s3://<bucket>/<endpoint>");
```

You'll probably want to use a more optimized output format than just a string, and also add a rolling policy so new files are automatically created.

[The docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#file-sink) show how to initialize Row or Bulk encoded file sinks that use other output encodings and are more flexible, but the idea would be similar.